# Database Oracle, Query Date String JPA Repository Crud Repository, Java 8

Tags: oracle, jpa, crud, spring-repositories

**NOTE:** I can't put some privated code (Database or Java Code).

I have in the Database

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."ENTITY" 
(   
    "HCODFECREGISTR" DATE,
    ... BLABLA
)
```

The Entity

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Entity  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Date hcodfecregistr;
     ....
}
```

In the **`Repository`** Interface
using

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;


public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long>, 
        JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    public static final String USING_STRING
    = " SELECT enti FROM Entity enti WHERE "
    + " (enti.hcodfecregistr BETWEEN TO_DATE(:stringIni,'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi') AND TO_DATE(:stringEnd,'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi'))";

    @Query(value = USING_STRING)
    List<Object[]> getEntityUsingString(
        @Param("stringIni") String stringIni, @Param("stringEnd") String stringEnd);


    public static final String USING_DATE
    = " SELECT enti FROM Entity enti WHERE "
    + " (enti.hcodfecregistr BETWEEN :dateIni AND :dateIni) ";

    @Query(value = USING_DATE)
    List<Object[]> getEntityUsingDate(
        @Param("dateIni") Date dateIni, @Param("dateEnd") Date dateEnd);


}
```

Now I want to perform a query.

```
Date fecha = //some java.util.Date

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fecha);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date dateIni = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    Date dateEnd = calendar.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String stringIni = dateFormat.format(fecha) + " 00:00";
    String stringEnd = dateFormat.format(fecha) + " 23:59";
```

**Works!**

```
    List<Object[]> listaObjects = theRepository.getEntityUsingString(stringIni, stringEnd);
```

**Fails!** It does not bring me results (but *it also does not show any error*).

```
    List<Object[]> listaObjects = theRepository.getEntityUsingDate(dateIni, dateEnd);
```

**Question:**

I want to understand Why using the same `fecha (java.util.Date)` the method `getEntityUsingString` works, but using the method `getEntityUsingDate` fails (
When I set the range using Date it does not bring me results, whereas when I set the range with String it does.).

In my opinion, it should yield the same result that complies with the range of dates.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You did not write what error it was, so it's only my guess that the most likely error in this case is:
 `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`.

If this is the case, then the reason is that you are passing to the query two values of **date type**:

```
Date dateIni = calendar.getTime();
.....
Date dateEnd = calendar.getTime();
.....
theRepository.getEntityUsingDate(dateIni, dateEnd);
```

these values are bind to this parameters `:stringIni` and `:stringEnd`

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE(:stringIni,'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi') AND TO_DATE(:stringEnd,'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Since [TO_DATE( char, [format] )](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) functions expects CHAR (string) as a first parameter, but gets a date, then according to rules explained in this documentation [see section: implicit conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51045)

> **The following rules govern implicit data type conversions**: 
> ....
>  ....
>   When you use a SQL function or operator with an argument of a data
>   type other than the one it accepts, Oracle converts the argument to
>   the accepted data type.

it does an implicit conversion from date to string using [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) function.
This function uses the default date language from a session to format strings, so depending of this settings the date may be converted to something like `12/15/54`, `19-06-11 12:23 PM`, `JUN 23, 2019 13:20 AM +01` etc.
This string `12/15/54` is then passed to `TO_DATE(:stringIni,'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi')`, and because this sting doesnt match format string, the error is thrown: `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Comment: thank you for your time. The problem is:
When I set the range using Date it does not bring me results, whereas when I set the range with String it does. But it also does not show me any error of format or sentence.